# how to increment and decrement date in asp.net

Tags: asp.net

### how to increment and decrement date in asp.net..

i have tried the following code..

### or is there any alternative like javascript..?

```
    {
      string dt;
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        dt = DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString().ToString();
        date.Text = dt;
    }

    protected void decr_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        date.Text = Convert.ToDateTime(date.Text).AddDays(-1).ToShortDateString().ToString();         
    }

    protected void incr_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        date.Text =Convert.ToDateTime(date.Text).AddDays(1).ToShortDateString().ToString();          
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wrap the code of the `Page_Load` event in `if (!Page.IsPostBack)`

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!Page.IsPostBack)
            {
                dt = DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString().ToString();
                date.Text = dt;
            }
        }
```